# $f(x,y)={{xy^3}\over {x+y^2}},(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ and $f(x,y)=0, (x,y)=(0,0)$

Tags: continuity

Compute $f_{xy}(0,0)$ and $f_{yx}(0,0)$ and also discuss the continuity of these two at that point. given that

$$f(x,y)={{xy^3}\over {x+y^2}},(x,y) \ne (0,0)$$ and $$f(0,0)=0.$$

I was able to find the two derivatives as $f_{xy}(0,0)=0$ and $f_{yx}(0,0)=1$. How do i go about the second part of the question where it asks to discuss the continuity ? Do i need to find the two partial derivatives and they check their continuity or there is a theoretical work around ?

Comment: I suggest that you compute the partial derivatives. You should find http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D[x+y^3%2F%28x%2By^2%29%2Cx%2Cy] and http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D[x+y^3%2F%28x%2By^2%29%2Cy%2Cx]

Comment: are you suggesting that the partial derivatives should actually be found and then checked for continuity ?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Since continuity is in question, investigating the derivative would not help (since there are continuous but nondifferentiable functions or worse see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariable_calculus). See http://www.math.jhu.edu/mathcourses/202/Florin_notes/notes_02-15-05.pdf as an example of how to investigate the continuity of multivariable.